# Given tangents from A and C, find minimum length of AC

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, circles, power-of-the-point

Let $ H $ be the intersection point of the heights of the acute-angled triangle $ ABC $. From points $ A $ and $ C $, tangents $ AK $ and $ CT $ are drawn to the circle drawn on the segment $ BH $ as on the diameter. Let $ 15 $ and $ 19 $ be the lengths of these tangents. What is the square of smallest possible $ AC $ side length?

It can be easy for me if it is with value. As It is an acute triangle, can't find the way. Please help me with a solution to go with this type in the future.

My Simple Answer:

$AK^2 + AC^2 = CT^2$

$15^2 + AC^2 = 19^2$

$AC^2 = 361 - 225$

$AC^2 = 136$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Triangle ABC]

Let the feet of perpendiculars from point $A$, $B$ and $C$ on the respective opposite sides be $D$, $E$ and $F$ respectively. The circle with diameter $BH$ will pass through points $D$ and $F$. Let the tangents from $A$ and $C$ to this circle be $AS$ and $CT$ respectively.

Considering the [power of points $A$ and $C$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) with respect to this circle gives,

$AS^{2}=AF\cdot AB$

$CT^{2}=CD\cdot BC$

Now, observe that, $CD\cdot BC=CE\cdot AC$ because $\triangle ACD\sim \triangle BCE$. Similarly, $AF\cdot AB=AE\cdot AC$ because $\triangle CAF\sim \triangle BAE$.

$\Rightarrow AS^{2}=AF\cdot AB=AE\cdot AC$ and similarly $CT^{2}=CE\cdot AC$.

Adding these two equations gives,
$AC^{2}=\boxed {AS^{2}+CT^{2}}$

Now plugging in the lengths of the tangents will give the value of $AC^{2}$.

Comment: Can you explain a little more "Considering the power of the points $A$ and $C$..." to justify the result following? Also later on clearly it's a mistake (typo?) to say $\triangle ACD\sim \triangle BED$

Comment: @Joffan Thank you very much for pointing out. It has been edited now. The power of a point is basically the square of the length of the tangent from that point to that circle. For more about this, check out this link : https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/PPower.shtml

Comment: @DRSKMOBINULHAQUE Nice answer! You can avoid similarity by using CDHE is cyclic. The solution then solely relies on power of point.

Comment: @cosmo5 Yes,  i thought of doing that but then i thought that both of them were essentially the same statement. Thanks!